# VBA How to stop ListBox from changing index focus

Tags: excel, vba

The **ListBox** is multicolumn and refers to a data in "Data_Output" sheet as below.

[image]

I need on Button Click to set Status of selected List index to "Closed" and "Date Finished" to current date with below code:

```
1 Private Sub FinishButton_Click()
2 
3 If Sheets("Data_Output").Cells(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex + 2, 1).Value = "Open" Then
4     Sheets("Data_Output").Cells(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex + 2, 4).Value = Date
5     Sheets("Data_Output").Cells(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex + 2, 1).Value = "Closed"
6 Else
7     MsgBox "Runsheet is not open. Runsheet should have open status to be closed."
8 End If

End Sub
```

The problem is that after execution of line 4, **ListIndex** selection skips to the top row of the list and **ListIndex** for the execution of line 5 is wrong.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Below code seems to be working well for me

```
Private Sub FinishButton_Click()

Dim selected_row As Integer
selected_row = Me.ListBox1.ListIndex

If Sheets("Data_Output").Cells(selected_row + 2, 1).Value = "Open" Then
    Sheets("Data_Output").Cells(selected_row + 2, 4).Value = Date
    Sheets("Data_Output").Cells(selected_row + 2, 1).Value = "Closed"
    Me.ListBox1.SetFocus
    Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = selected_row
Else
    MsgBox "Runsheet is not open. Runsheet should be open in order to be closed."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Take the details from the selected item before hand and use that

Comment: Thank you @Nathan_Sav seems to work. Code in the edited post.

Comment: My pleasure ...